# Testing in the Gin Go Framework

Tags: go, testing

I have searched everywhere for information on how to resolve this issue. I am not getting full coverage on testing of a Gin GET call in Go.

I am calling the test and the results are at 50% for the function and i cannot seem to get the results to 100%.

[Here is the code and the coverage output html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBNUS.jpg)

This is the Go code

```
var JSONGET = func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "code":     http.StatusOK,
       "endpoint": c.Request.RequestURI,
        "response": gin.H{
            "body": "GET Response",
            "type": "text",
        },
        "status": "http.StatusOK",
        "type":   "GET",
    })
}

// PingGET ...
func PingGET(c *gin.Context) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return JSONGET
}
```

This is the test function

```
func TestPingGET(t *testing.T) {
    response := httptest.NewRecorder()
    context, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(response)

    fmt.Println(response.Code)
    PingGET(context)
    fmt.Println(response.Code)

    if response.Code != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("Error PingGET failed")
    }
}
```

Here is the output html but you will need to view the picture for more clarification about which are the parts that aren't being tested.

```
package handler

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

// JSONGET ...
var JSONGET = func(c *gin.Context) **{
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "code":     http.StatusOK,
            "endpoint": c.Request.RequestURI,
            "response": gin.H{
                "body": "GET Response",
                 "type": "text",
            },
            "status": "http.StatusOK",
            "type":   "GET",
        })
    }**

// PingGET ...
func PingGET(c *gin.Context) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return JSONGET
}
```

If anyone can explain how to resolve this and/or explain this?

Comment: You are calling PingGET, which is returning a function. That returned function is never called.

Comment: So i have to create another function to Test the code that isn't being tested?

Comment: You need to call it: JSONGET(ctx)

Comment: Thank you @BurakSerdar i didn't research the gin documentation and i found my answer there. Thank you for helping tho :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found here: [GinDocs](https://gin-gonic.com/docs/testing/)